# CSS: How to put text inside an icon?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic app and I'm displaying some [info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIp8m.png) in rounded areas, but I need to put the number into the heart icon in the second area. I need them to be vertically and horizontally aligned, and that the number looks like inside of the heart. I've been trying some things but I can't achieve all at once. How can I do that? Thanks.

**NOTE**: The text is dynamic, it's a percentage which can be 0% to 100%

This is the code for that area

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="post-info">
  <span class="charity">
    <i class="ion-ios-heart-outline"></i><span style="font-size: 13px">45</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make icon as a container for text by setting position `relative` for icon and putting the text in `:before`peseudo with position absolute

https://jsfiddle.net/Ljquqtrv/

Comment: Man I love this answer, but the text is dynamic. :(

Comment: i'll try to find solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="post-info">
  <span class="charity">
      <span style="font-size: 13px;position:absolute;text-align:center;width:26px;padding-top:3px">55</span>
      <i style="font-size:30px" class="ion-ios-heart-outline"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Centers text based on value, ie single digit is centered as well as two numbers.
You can absolute position the number on top of the icon using 'position:absolute;' 
Also you can use css/javascript/jquery to center it with 'top:XXpx;left:XXpx;'
jsfiddle to follow soon.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0eeuf7ew/1)

```
.charity > .inner-num {
  position:absolute;  
  left:10px;
  top:10px;
  width:20px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't put text into an icon. Make the icon a background image of a div. Then put the numbers inside the div.